# Accessing array object variables when implementing RecursiveArrayIterator in RecursiveIteratorIterator

Tags: php, spl, arrayiterator

I have a large arrayObject which I'm looping over using the following:-

```
$rit = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($hierarchy));
foreach($rit as $key=> $val) {

}
```

How can I access the a specific key within the array? I can access them by echoing $key and the $val but I have specific keys I wish to access. If I attempt to call $key[''] I get the first letter on the key name.

Edit 1

Some sample data (There can be many different sub-children too):

```
ArrayObject::__set_state(array(
   0 => 
  ArrayObject::__set_state(array(
     0 => 
    array (
      'id' => '8755',
      'company_id' => '1437',
      'name' => 'Name 1'
    ),
     1 => 
    ArrayObject::__set_state(array(
       0 => 
      ArrayObject::__set_state(array(
         0 => 
        array (
          'id' => '8763',
          'company_id' => '1437',
          'name' => 'Name 2'
        ),
         1 => 
        ArrayObject::__set_state(array(
           0 => 
          ArrayObject::__set_state(array(
             0 => 
            array (
              'id' => '9067',
              'company_id' => '1437',
              'name' => 'Name 3'
            ),
          )),
           1 => 
          ArrayObject::__set_state(array(
             0 => 
            array (
              'id' => '8765',
              'company_id' => '1437',
              'name' => 'Name 4'
            ),
          )),
           2 => 
          ArrayObject::__set_state(array(
             0 => 
            array (
              'id' => '9049',
              'company_id' => '1437',
              'name' => 'Name 5'
            ),
          )),
           3 => 
          ArrayObject::__set_state(array(
             0 => 
            array (
              'id' => '8769',
              'company_id' => '1437',
              'name' => 'Name 6'
            ),
          )),
```

Comment: To help us to help you, what does `$hierarchy->getArrayCopy()` return? (i.e. show us the structure in array form, for us to work with your example)  Also your question is not clear: do you want to access only the single item somewhere within the hierarchy, based on its "key"? (which will be what, its id number, some path/position?)

Comment: Can you please clarify what you are trying to achieve? In your comment an an answer below you said you wanted to "display the array as a representation on-screen". I'm afraid I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Sure. Basically this array is generated from an existing function. The array holds a structural representation of the relationships between departments.

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is displaying this on-screen in a hierarchical format whereby the user can opt to check a department which selects all sub-departments so on and so on.

Comment: Let me get a copy of what $hierarchy->getArrayCopy() outputs.

Comment: In fact the above var_export() is a representation of what $hierarchy is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the RecursiveIteratorIterator will only list the leaves. Try

```
$rit = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
           new RecursiveArrayIterator($hierarchy),
           RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
```

to get the containing elements as well.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `$hierarchy` is your large array, you can use `$hierarchy["foo"]` to access the value associated with the `foo` key. Or like this:

```
$my_key = "foo"
echo $hierarchy[$my_key]
// Same as
echo $hierarchy["foo"]
```

Comment: That's what I thought but it isn't.

Comment: What do you get when you `print_r($heirarchy)`?

Comment: Above is the original dump of $hierarchy before I pass it into RecursiveArrayIterator. What I'm trying to do is display the array as a representation on-screen with checkboxes next to each level in order to assign rights to each department.